# Using different size classes, views disappear from storyboard scene

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout, scene, size-classes

I am trying to design my app for landscape orientation. Here is my app in regular orientation:
[image: regular]

In landscape:
[image: landscape]

See how my buttons just disappeared and are off the scene? How can I access them to move them?

Comment: you could programmatically design them. If `orientation == do one design, else if to other design`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click on them then go to the size inspector in the right-panel of the interface builder. There you can change the X and Y values manually (or you can just change them to X:0 and Y:0 so they pop to the upper-left corner of the screen so you can move them with your mouse).

Comment: When I say "click on them", I mean in the document outline panel on the left of Interface Builder where it lists all the items in the view heirarchy.

Comment: Thanks, not sure why I didn't think of that. Also not sure why there isn't a more intuitive way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

> Move back to the Portrait orientation move the views in the bottom
>   part to the top. Then, re-select the Landscape orinetation again!